# My program executes the loops the correct # of times, but I cannot see the string variable?

Tags: c++

Since the program executes the loops the correct amount of times, we know the division is working, however I cannot seem to get the output of whatever is in the string variable "result." Any help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int base,decimal,remainder;
  string result;


  cout <<"Welcome to the Base Converter.  Please enter in the requested        base from 2-16"<<endl;
  cout <<"and an integer greater than or equal to zero and this will     convert to the new base."<<endl
  do
  {
    cout <<"Please enter the requested base from 2-16:"<<endl;
    cin >>base;
    }while (base<2 || base>16);
  do
  {
    cout <<"Please enter the requested integer to convert from base  10:"<<endl;
    cin >>decimal;
    }while (decimal<0);

  do
  {
    decimal=decimal/base;
    remainder=decimal%base;
    if (remainder<=9)
    {
      string remainder;
      result=remainder+result;
     }
    else
    {
      switch(remainder)
      {
        case 10:
          {
            result="A"+result;
            }
```

There are some more cases for my switch, but I believe the problem is somewhere in my variable declaration or my string class.  Any obvious solutions?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to execute your code, one line at a time, and you examined all your variables, what observations have you made in your debugger?

Comment: What is the purpose of  `string remainder;`? I mean you declare a string named remainder of the same name of your integer remainder. You don't put anything in the sting `remainder` then do this `result=remainder+result;`

Comment: Very new to C++, but nothing seemed to be out of the ordinary in the debugger, and everything compiled cleanly.

Comment: In the debugger you are supposed to single step through each line of your code looking at the variables to see if your calculations are producing the result you expect.

Comment: I was also under the impression that since I was adding a variable of type INT to a STRING, it would be necessary to redeclare it as a string type(when I did not, my compiler would not accept adding the different variable types).

Comment: @Zack, string remainder;       result=remainder+result; is always empty if the remainder is <=9. Please rename one of your remainder variable to different one and check. And please let us know if it fixed it.

Comment: ***redeclare it as a string type*** In c++ you are just declaring a new variable with the same name but in a different scope. It will not have anything to do with the original int variable (meaning it will be empty). It will actually mask out the int variable in the local scope (so you will have no access to the integer in the scope that the string exists).

Comment: @IIgorbek which remainder term would you suggest renaming?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is incomplete and I can't be sure if this is the correct solution without seeing the rest of the function. However, the way you modify your `result` variable in the snippet you have posted is clearly incorrect.

When you declare a local variable with the same name as another variable in the given context, it hides the earlier declared one. So if you write

```
int remainder = 0;
std::string result = "";
if (remainder<=9)
{
    std::string remainder; //this hides the outer-scope remainder variable for this code block
    result=remainder+result;
}
```

it's the same as if you have written

```
result = "" + result;
```

which is clearly a no-op.

To prepend the `remainder` value to a string you should do it like that:

```
if (remainder<=9)
{
    std::string remainder_str = std::to_string(remainder); //note different name and initialization value
    result = remainder_str + result;
}
```

or simply

```
result = std::to_string(remainder) + result;
```

Please note that [to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is available since C++11 in header `<string>`. If you can't use C+11, you could use [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/) instead.

Comment: Upon trying to compile my program with this, I get an error saying: "error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
       result= std::to_string(remainder) +result;"

Comment: [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is available since C++11 in header `<string>`. Make sure you have those available or replace it with [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/)